# Update data in database using Axios and VueJS

Tags: html, node.js, express, vue.js, axios

I have this program which gets an entry from a database. It then changes some of the fields in this object and then sends it back with a **PUT** using **Axios**. My problem is that I don't know what to write in the **PUT-function** on the server side. When I try to do a **PUT-request** that only **console.log** the values I get the error:

> "PayloadTooLargeError: Request entity too large".

**selectedRoute** contains the ID of the object to be sent back. **chosenRoute** contains the object.

Client-side:

```
onUpload(): void {
    console.log(this.chosenRoute);
    this.chosenRoute.name = this.routeName;
    this.chosenRoute.text.paragraphs[0] = this.routeDescription;
    this.chosenRoute.text.preamble;
    if(this.activity != "") this.chosenRoute.activity = this.activity;
    axios.put('http://localhost:8080/editRoute/' + this.selectedRoute, this.chosenRoute, {
    onUploadProgress: uploadEvent => {
      console.log('Upload Progress ' + Math.round(uploadEvent.loaded / uploadEvent.total) * 100 + " % ");
    }
  }).then(
      res => {
      console.log(res);
  });
 }
```

Server-side:

```
app.put('/editRoute/:id', function(req,res){
    console.log(req);
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: `axios.post('http://localhost:8080/editR...` etc. instead of axios.put

Comment: @Andrew1325 What would be the improvement using post?

Comment: Because the URI must be the address to the resource being updated. Which from the client it isn't. From the server it is. As for what goes into the server side request, that would depend on what your db is. I got the bit about put vs post from [here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/rest/put-versus-post)